# Laravel: Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using the below Mailtrap configuration for my Laravel (5.3) Homestead app but I get the following error whenever I use the Mail Facade

`Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""`

### .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=**************
MAIL_PASSWORD=**************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

### Controller

```
    public function send()
    {
      $result = Mail::send('emails.test',['content' => 'This is the email Content'], function($message) {
        $message->from('noreply@mydomain.com');
        $message->to('my@email.com')
        ->subject('Test Email');

      });

      return $result;
    }
```

I've tried `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` but I end up with `Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [ #0]`

Could someone advice or probably tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` 
. Also check this link [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/mailtrap-laravel?page=1]

Comment: if problem persists change `MAIL_PORT=587`

Comment: Thanks @Manish, Turns out I had to change port. The alternative port is 465 and not 587

Comment: My pleasure. But i recommend to use [https://www.mailgun.com/] or [http://mailchimp.com/].

They are free at some level. and have lots of benefits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally fixed my issue.

I had to change MailTrap configuration

from

```
MAIL_PORT=2525
```

to

```
MAIL_PORT=465
```

Thanks to @Manish for spotting that in the comments.

Comment: Changing the port worked. For me, using port 465 timed out in the request but port 25 fixed my issue